# Randomly generated public unique ids

Tags: uniqueidentifier, unique-index

Currently I'm generating unique ids for rows in my database using int and auto_increment. These ids are public facing so in the url you can see something like this `https://example.com/path/1` or `https://example.com/path/2`

After talking with another engineer they've advised me that I should use randomly generated ids so that they're not guessable.

How can I generate a unique ID & without doing a forloop on the database each time to make sure it's unique? e.g. take stripe for example. All of their ids are `price_sdfgsdfg` or `prod_iisdfgsdfg`. Whats the best way to generate unique ids for rows like these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing which language or database you're using, the simplest way is using `uuid`s.

To prevent downloading all existing database unique keys, and then for looping over them all, simply just try to `INSERT INTO` whichever table you are using.

If the result fails (e.g. Exception), then the row is taken, continue.

If the result passes, break loop.

This only works when you have a column which is `NOT NULL`, and `UNIQUE`.

That's how I "know" without looping over the whole database of IDs, or downloading them into local memory, etc.

Using `auto_increment` wont lead to duplicates because when a SQL or no-SQL table is in use, it will be **locked** and given to the next available number in the queue, which is the beauty of databases.

SQL example (mySQL, SQLite, mariadb):

```
CREATE TABLE `my_db`.`my_table` ( `unique_id` INT NOT NULL , UNIQUE (`unique_id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;`
```

Insert a unique_id

```sql
INSERT INTO `test` (`unique_id`) VALUES ('999999999');
```

Great, we have a row

```sql
INSERT INTO `test` (`unique_id`) VALUES ('999999999');
```

If not, then retry:

Error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '999999999' for key 'unique_id'
```

If these are public URLs, and the content is sensitive, then I definitely do not recommend `int`'s as someone can trivially guess 1 through 99999999... etc.

In any language, have a look at `/dev/urandom`.

In shell/bash scripts, I might use `uuidgen`:
9dccd646-043e-4984-9126-3060b4ced180

In Python, I'll use pandas:

```
df.set_index(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df, encoding='utf8'), drop=True, inplace=True)
df.index.rename('hash', inplace=True)
```

Lastly, UUID's aren't perfect: they are only a-f 0-9 all lowercase, but they are easy to generate: every language has one.

In JavaScript you may want to check out some secure Open Source apps, for example, Jitsi: https://github.com/jitsi/js-utils/blob/master/random/roomNameGenerator.js where they conjugate word:

E.g. `Satisfied-Global-Architectural-Bitter`